# Cascading Referential Integrity Constraints for many to many relationships in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, many-to-many

I'm using EF Core 3.1.5 with Asp.Net Core 3.1. When I'm trying to Add-Migration I get next error:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_PhotoDevice_Device_DeviceId' on table 'PhotoDevice' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

I have next entities and configuration:

```
public class User {
   [Key]
   public long Id { get; set; }
   // Fields
   public IEnumerable<Device> Devices { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<Photo> Photos { get; set; }
}

public class Photo {
   [Key]
   public long Id { get; set; }
   // Fields
   [ForeignKey("User")]
   public long UserRef { get; set; }
   public User User { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<PhotoDevice> PhotoDevices { get; set; }
}

public class Device {
   [Key]
   public long Id { get; set; }
   // Fields
   [ForeignKey("User")]
   public long UserRef { get; set; }
   public User User { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<PhotoDevice> PhotoDevices { get; set; }
}

public class PhotoDevice {
{
   public long? PhotoRef { get; set; }
   public Photo Photo { get; set; }

   public long? DeviceRef { get; set; }
   public Device Device { get; set; }
}

public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
   public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
   public DbSet<Photo> Photos { get; set; }
   public DbSet<Device> Devices { get; set; }
   public DbSet<PhotoDevice> PhotoDevices { get; set; }
   public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options)
   : base(options)
   {
      Database.Migrate();
   }

   protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
   {
      builder.Entity<Photo>()
         .HasOne(photo => photo.User)
         .WithMany(user => user.Photos);

      builder.Entity<Device>()
         .HasOne(device => device.User)
         .WithMany(user => user.Devices);

      builder.Entity<PhotoDevice>()
         .HasKey(bc => new { bc.PhotoRef, bc.DeviceRef });
      builder.Entity<PhotoDevice>()
         .HasOne(bc => bc.Photo)
         .WithMany(b => b.PhotoDevices)
         .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.PhotoRef);
      builder.Entity<PhotoDevice>()
         .HasOne(bc => bc.Device)
         .WithMany(c => c.PhotoDevices)
         .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.DeviceRef);
   }
}
```

I found that problem is related to not uniqueness of cascading connections. But now I'm confused. Because I think that this structure is necessary and I don't want to drop any FK. How can I fix the problem If I need next logic:

- When User deleted all devices and photos related to the user are also removed
- When Device or Photo deleted all PhotoDevice records related to the deleted entity are removed too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to drop any of your foreign keys. Just use `OnDelete(DeleteBehavior)` to explicitly specify what kind of cascading behavior you need.

For example, the following would result in your model being created successfully, but for your real application, you need to decide yourself where and how to **break the cascade**:

```cs
builder.Entity<PhotoDevice>()
    .HasOne(bc => bc.Photo)
    .WithMany(b => b.PhotoDevices)
    .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.PhotoRef)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict); // <-- define cascading behavior
```

For further information, see [Relationships: Cascade delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#cascade-delete) and [Cascade Delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete).

This is not an EF Core, but a **SQL Server limitation** (therefore the exception is also thrown by SQL Server).

Here are further resources, that deal with this limitation and show how to **work around** it, by using `INSTEAD OF` trigger, if breaking the cascade is not an option you can live with:

- [Solving the SQL Server Multiple Cascade Path Issue with a Trigger](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2733/solving-the-sql-server-multiple-cascade-path-issue-with-a-trigger/)
- [Preferred design to avoid circular/multiple update paths](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/184832/preferred-design-to-avoid-circular-multiple-update-paths)

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is really complete and helped me figure out the problem

Answer (score 1):

What lauxjpn said is correct, but please note that when you add `.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);`
to your context after that, please remember to delete all your previous migrations, otherwise it will still report an error.