# Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'X' on table 'Y' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.2

I know that there are multiple questions regarding this error message, but I didn't found something that will help me.
I have this situation:

**User Model**

```
public class User : IdentityUser<int>
{
    ......
    public virtual ICollection<Like> Likers { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Like> Likees { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Message> MessagesSent { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Message> MessagesReceived { get; set; }
}
```

**Like Model**

```
public class Like
{
    public int LikerId { get; set; }
    public int LikeeId { get; set; }
    public virtual User Liker { get; set; }
    public virtual User Likee { get; set; }
}
```

**Message Model**

```
public class Message
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int SenderId { get; set; }
    public virtual User Sender { get; set; }
    public int RecipientId { get; set; }
    public virtual User Recipient { get; set; }
    .....
}
```

**In DataContext**

```
.....
builder.Entity<Like>()
    .HasKey(k => new { k.LikerId, k.LikeeId });

builder.Entity<Like>()
    .HasOne(u => u.Likee)
    .WithMany(u => u.Likers)
    .HasForeignKey(u => u.LikeeId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

builder.Entity<Like>()
    .HasOne(u => u.Liker)
    .WithMany(u => u.Likees)
    .HasForeignKey(u => u.LikerId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

builder.Entity<Message>()
    .HasOne(u => u.Sender)
    .WithMany(u => u.MessagesSent)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);


builder.Entity<Message>()
    .HasOne(u => u.Recipient)
    .WithMany(u => u.MessagesReceived)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
.....
```

If I have `.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);` I recieve this error messaage when I try to apply the migration:
`An error occured during migration Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Likes_AspNetUsers_LikerId' on table 'Likes' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.`
Same error for both **Likes** and **Messages** tables.

A solution it will be to add `.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);`, but if I want to add an option in the application to delete an user, I can't do it if the user liked someone or if he sent a message. First I will need to manually delete all his likes and his messages and after that to perform the user delete, that's why I want to this automatically with Cascade Delete.

This error message occurs only when I'm using Microsoft SQL Server, it works with SQLite.

**Edit:**
As a workaround I chose what @lauxjpn sugested and changed from `.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Delete);` to `.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);` and created a [DB Trigger](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2733/solving-the-sql-server-multiple-cascade-path-issue-with-a-trigger/) to handle the deletion of the child records (Likes and Messages) before the deletion of the parent.
I tested this approach and it works. First I logged in with a new user, liked someone and sent a message and after that I deleted my account. The trigger took care of the rest, removed the records from Likes and Messages and after that the User from AspNetUsers.

This is the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [DELETE_User]
   ON [dbo].[AspNetUsers]
   INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;
 DELETE FROM [dbo].[Likes] WHERE LikerId IN (SELECT Id FROM DELETED)
 DELETE FROM [dbo].[Likes] WHERE LikeeId IN (SELECT Id FROM DELETED)
 DELETE FROM [dbo].[Messages] WHERE SenderId IN (SELECT Id FROM DELETED)
 DELETE FROM [dbo].[Messages] WHERE RecipientId IN (SELECT Id FROM DELETED)
 DELETE FROM [dbo].[AspNetUsers] WHERE Id IN (SELECT Id FROM DELETED)
END
```

**Edit 2:** (Maybe someone else will need this)
The trigger can also be added in a migration:

```
public partial class AddedInstedOfTrigger : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.Sql(@"
        CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER [DELETE_User]
          ON [dbo].[AspNetUsers]
          INSTEAD OF DELETE
        AS
        BEGIN
          SET NOCOUNT ON;
          DELETE FROM [dbo].[Likes] WHERE LikerId IN (SELECT Id FROM DELETED)
          DELETE FROM [dbo].[Likes] WHERE LikeeId IN (SELECT Id FROM DELETED)
          DELETE FROM [dbo].[Messages] WHERE SenderId IN (SELECT Id FROM DELETED)
          DELETE FROM [dbo].[Messages] WHERE RecipientId IN (SELECT Id FROM DELETED)
          DELETE FROM [dbo].[AspNetUsers] WHERE Id IN (SELECT Id FROM DELETED)
        END");
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.Sql(@"DROP TRIGGER [DELETE_User]");
    }
}
```

Comment: SQL Server doesn't allow multiple trees that then merge like that to have cascading. If you have multiple merging branches, only one of them can have cascading, while you'll have the handle the other in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently gave an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63020578/2618319) to the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63020243/cascading-referential-integrity-constraints-for-many-to-many-relationships-in-ef) here on SO:

> You don't need to drop any of your foreign keys. Just use `OnDelete(DeleteBehavior)` to explicitly specify what kind of cascading behavior you need.
>
> For example, the following would result in your model being created successfully, but for your real application, you need to decide yourself where and how to **break the cascade**:

```cs
builder.Entity<PhotoDevice>()
    .HasOne(bc => bc.Photo)
    .WithMany(b => b.PhotoDevices)
    .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.PhotoRef)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict); // <-- define cascading behavior
```

> For further information, see [Relationships: Cascade delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#cascade-delete) and [Cascade Delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete).
>
> This is not an EF Core, but a **SQL Server limitation** (therefore the exception is also thrown by SQL Server).
>
> Here are further resources, that deal with this limitation and show how to **work around** it, by using `INSTEAD OF` trigger, if breaking the cascade is not an option you can live with:
>
> - [Solving the SQL Server Multiple Cascade Path Issue with a Trigger](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2733/solving-the-sql-server-multiple-cascade-path-issue-with-a-trigger/)
> - [Preferred design to avoid circular/multiple update paths](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/184832/preferred-design-to-avoid-circular-multiple-update-paths)

Comment: So, from what I understand I have 2 options: 1. Use .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict); and handle the Cascade Delete in the code 2. Use .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict); and handle the Cascade Delete with a INSTEAD OF trigger in DB. I chose option 2 and it worked. I will also edit my post. Thanks!